# String Compare fails - JavaScript IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, asp.net-4.0, string-comparison

I am trying to filter data from HTML table using JavaScript and it is doing something almost hard to figure out. the string comparison fails. I also tried not to do comparison b/w primitive and object (the watch values in the screeen-shot attached) I tried following, 
and in these expressions Left Hand Side < Right Hand Side (localeCompare also returned -1 ) ... am I missing something ?

```
condition = $(this).text().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').toString() == columnName.toString(); //false
condition = $(this).text() == columnName; //false
condition = $(this).text().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '') == columnName.toString(); // false
condition = $(this).text().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').toLocaleString().localeCompare(columnName.toLocaleString()); // -1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a space at the end of columnName's value in the debugger there...

You should probably trim columnName or something if this is a possible issue; I notice you're already trimming the value you're comparing against.

Comment: Thanks, my eyes are playing tricks with me. I could have noticed this myself :-/ I trusted that paritally because it was working before for some reason and I added other functianolity